# Background scaled/magnified in Iphone4 and 5 simulator ? Using plain HTML5 and CSS3 code

Tags: iphone, html, css, media-queries

Developing HTML5 app for iphone4 and 5. I have texture rich background. When i tried to add this texture image, its getting scaled and only central part is visible. Image size is 640x960 and 640x1136, even after adding @2x at the end, its still scaling and i want whole image visible. Please find code below-

code:

```
 <div id="container" data-role="page" class="login_bg">
  <section class="main" data-role="none">
....

....
 </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media all and (min-width: 640px) and (max-height: 960px){

    .login_bg {
        width:100%; 
        height:960px;
        background-image:url(../../img/Bg_960@2x.png);  
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position: top center;
        background-size:cover; 
    }

}


@media all and (min-width: 640px) and (max-height: 1136px){

.login_bg {
    width:100%; 
    height:1136px;
    background-image:url(../../img/Bg_1136@2x.png);     
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size:cover;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a problem, just need to add below media query for Iphone Retina-

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
       only screen and (min-resolution: 200dpi)
  { ....
```

}

Normal media query like -

@media all and (min-width: 640px) and (max-height: 960px){}

or

@media all and (min-width: 640px) and (max-height: 1136px){}

WILL NOT WORK.

I wasted 3 days to figure this out. Hope this will help people to save their time. :)